# Exibir imagens da direita para a esquerda

Tags: html, css

Atualmente estou tendo um problema com meu código pois eu preciso que as imagens sejam exibidas na tela mas que ela venham da direita para esquerda. O padrão é a gente colocar os códigos `<img>` e ela são vão exibindo as imagens da esquerda para direita. Só que quero que ao colocar os códigos `<img>` as imagens comecem a ser exibidas da direita para a esquerda. Atualmente estou com o código:

**CSS**

```
#includeload {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

#align-rodape {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

#pagina-projetos {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

**Estrutura HTML**

```
<div id="pagina-projetos">
    <h1 class="page-header">Projetos</h1>

    <div id="align-rodape" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="image-row">
            <div id="includeload" class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="submenu" page="comercial">Comercial</a> | 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="submenu" page="industrial">Industrial</a> |
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Teria como você fazer um pequeno exemplo no jsfiddle? Juro que estou me esforçando, mas não estou entendendo o que você está tentando alinhar...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mxbwavdo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente o que você quer é algo deste tipo:

```css
#includeload{height:300px;width:100%;}
#align-rodape{position: absolute;margin-top: 150px;}
#pagina-projetos{min-height: 100%;display: none;margin-top:70px;}
#includeload img {float:right}
```

Comment: com esse código, quando completar o `width` da tela, as imagens anteriores sobem pra linha de cima? porque eu quero fazer assim. Assim que completar o width as imagens q já estavam listada na tela, sobem para a linha de cima envez de jogar pra linha de baixo.

Comment: Na verdade nao sobe nada, as seguintes é que ficam na linha de baixo. Ficaria assim: Linha1: 4 3 2 1 Linha 2: ... 6 5

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois formatação de código (desde que correta e consistente) é gosto individual. Não há motivo pra ficar fazendo uma linguiça com código desse tipo. Além do quê, eu estava respeitando a intenção original do autor.

Comment: PS: Acho que a falha é de quem aprovou, e não do @Juliano, que sugeriu.

Answer (score 1):

`float:right` nas imgs não resolve? Consegui fazer funcionar no seu Jfiddle

```
img {float:right}
```

Comment: @Bacco pois é. Basta isso, não?

Comment: Até então o OP não havia dado o accept na resposta, então eu respondi baseado em uma suposição. Agora, com o accept, eu imagino que seja isso de fato.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas completando com outra forma de se fazer.
Usando o atributo `dir="rtl"`.
Feito justamente para direcionar o texto - `DIR-ESQ` | `ESQ-DIR`, muito usado para alinhar o layout para idiomas que se escrevem da direita para esquerda.

`<div dir="rtl">`
[**<sub>Veja um exemplo em funcionamento</sub>**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcvdzcg2/)